# How to get result value range in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

All:

I am new to MongoDB and I wonder if I search a field, how can I get the value range base on the results:

There mainly two things I want to ask:

- How can I find range of certain field based on results from previous search (like a subquery)?

For example:

If I search `{"product_name": "pname1"}`, and I get several results, then I want to know the price range (suppose each document has a field called price) of those products with name `"pname1"`.

- How can I directly get the range from certain field when using range search?

For example:

If I search `{"price": {$gt: 100}}`, and I get several results, then I want to know the price range of those products with price larger than 100

Thanks

Comment: for your second query, what do you mean by saying price range? You want to know the price range for **each product** that has price grater that 100?

Comment: @n9code What I mean is: suppose there are products with price 100, 105, 200, 300, 306, ...., all those products will return as results when I use  {"price": {$gt: 100}}, but I want to know what is the smallest price above 100, and what is the largest price. BTW, how to use BOLD font in comment?

Comment: updated my answer for second part. for **bold** enclose your text inside double `**`s ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first part**

For your first query you can use MongoDB's `aggregation framework`, and specifically the `$first` and `$last` operations. Particularly, you can query your collection to get the price range for all the products in the following way:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
                               {$sort: 
                                        {
                                           "product_name": 1, 
                                           "price": 1
                                        }
                               },
                               {
                                  $group:
                                           {
                                              _id: "$product_name",
                                              min_price: {$first: "$price"},
                                              max_price: {$last: "$price"},
                                           }
                               }
                           ])
```

So if you want the information for a particular product, just add a `$match` stage to your aggregation pipeline:

```
{
   $match: {"product_name": "<the product of interest>"}
}
```

**The second part**

And something similar for the second query.

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
                               {
                                  $match: {
                                             "price": {$gt: 100}
                                          }
                               },
                               {
                                  $group: {
                                             _id: "$price",
                                             products: {$push: "$product_name"} 
                                          }
                               },
                               {
                                  $sort: {_id: 1}
                               }
                               {
                                  $group: {
                                             _id: null,
                                             min_price_products: {$first: "$products"},
                                             mix_price: {$first: "$_id"},
                                             max_price_products: {$last: "$products"},
                                             max_price: {$last: "$_id"}
                                          }
                               }
                           ])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is aggregation framework present in mongodb which can provide a functionality where two or more operations can be combined together.

It provides us with the max and min values of a particular field satisfying a particular query using $match and $group operators. It can be used to find the range.

For the given use case the query looks something like:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {"product_name":"pname1"}}, {$group :{_id:null , maxValue:{$max:"$price"}, minValue:{$min:"$price"}}}]);
```

Here the query is present inside $match, and max and min values are present inside $group functionality of aggregation.

A detailed description can be found in the links below:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look at it